# install opentoonz on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

I have seen the software opentoonz for creating animations, and I am trying to install it.

during compilation, the install fails at:

```
OpenBLAS:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.so
***** LZO Header path:LZO_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
***** LZO Library path:LZO_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LZO (missing: LZO_LIBRARY LZO_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/m/opentoonz/toonz/cmake/FindLZO.cmake:56 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:471 (find_package)
```

I have installed liblz4-dev, is this a python package I am missing or a standard package?
I was following instructions from the source page, but there is no detail on this error.

I tried installing the snap version, which does install, but warns of an updated version every time. Clicking a link puts me on the website, with no clear way to actually update, so I figured I would install from source code, but this is where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I installed liblzo2-dev:

```
sudo apt install liblzo2-dev
```

And than it worked.